# Adding A popup in javascript when a string is a specific value

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<   <td id='chemicalName'><c:out value="${masterChemRow.chemicalName}"/>
                        <c:if test = "${fn:containsIgnoreCase(masterChemRow.chemicalName,Unknown) }">
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                alert(" CHANGE MESSAGE:ENTER MESSAGE HERE")
                            </script>
                        </c:if>
```

For this code here I am trying to add a pop up window When masterChemRow.chemicalName.equals("Unknown" || "unknown") I want an alert to pop up How would i go about this? Here is what I currently have working which displays a pop up box. But is there a better way? My current pop up works. The only issue I am having is when I press okay it does not disappear.

Comment: My current pop up works, the only issue is when I press okay it does not go away.

Comment: Avoid using comments to add info. Edit your original question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
 <c:if test = "${masterChemRow.chemicalName.equals("Unknown") || 
                        masterChemRow.chemicalName.equals("unknown")}">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            alert(" CHANGE MESSAGE:ENTER MESSAGE HERE")
                        </script>
                    </c:if>
```